# Expanding the power series $\prod_{i\geq 1}(1+x_i+x_i^2)$

Tags: combinatorics

How do I expand the power series $$\prod_{i\geq 1}(1+x_i+x_i^2)$$ in terms of the elementary symmetric functions?

Thanks!

Comment: The elementary symmetric functions are usually defined on $(x_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$ for some finite $n$, not on $(x_i)_{i\geqslant1}$. Are you sure you want to consider an infinite product? // Oh, and by the way, what did you try?

Comment: This makes sense in the ring of symmetric functions, infinite or otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

\begin{align}
\prod_{i \geq 1}1+x_i+x_i^2&=\prod_{i \geq 1}(1-\omega x_i)(1-\omega^2 x_i)
\\
\\
&=\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^n\omega^ne_n\times\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\omega^{2n}e_n
\\
\\
&=\sum_ne^2_n+\sum_{n>m}[(-1)^{m+n}\omega^{m+2n}+(-1)^{m+n}\omega^{2m+n}]e_me_n
\\
\\
&=\sum_ne^2_n+\sum_{n>m}(-1)^{m+n}\omega^{m+2n}e_me_n+\sum_{n>m}(-1)^{m+n}\omega^{2m+n}e_me_n
\\
\\
&=\sum_ne^2_n+\sum_{n>m}c_{mn}e_me_n
\end{align}

where $\omega$ stands for a primitive cube root of unity.